# Piping into Dieharder with Python

Tags: python, random

I am trying to pipe a stream of random numbers generated by the Blum Blum Shub PRNG into the Dieharder randomness tests with the command

```
python generator.py | dieharder -a -g 200
```

if `generator.py` is the script containing the BBS pseudo random number generator. If `f` is the BBS pseudo random generator, and `currx` is the next value generated by the generator, I am piping a continuous stream of random numbers into Dieharder with the following (updating `currx` at every iteration).

```
while True:
    currx = f(currx)
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(struct.pack('>I', currx))
```

Where `currx` is an `int`.  Presently, the generator completely fails every randomness test:

```
     test_name   |ntup| tsamples |psamples|  p-value |Assessment 
#====================================================================#
diehard_birthdays|   0|       100|     100|0.00000000|  FAILED
```

which doesn't make sense because Blum Blum Shub is very good, and when I pass it through different random number testers like ENT it passes all the tests perfectly.  This likely means I am piping the data into Dieharder incorrectly.  Can anyone help me identify what may be wrong with my code?

The Dieharder manual gives

> Raw binary input reads 32 bit increments of the specified data 
>   stream. stdin_input_raw accepts a pipe from a raw binary stream.

however from what I can tell my implementation satisfies this.  Where am I wrong?